# How do I copy a row from one sheet to another if there is an intersection of certain columns

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Given:

I have a document `grumble.xlsx`

with 3 tabs inside: `Sheet1 Sheet2 and Sheet 3`

```
Sheet 1 has 588 rows and 11 columns of data

Sheet 2 has 3029 rows and 17 columns of data

Sheet 3 in empty
```

Aim:

If value of a sheet1 column_name S2 == to a value of a sheet2 column_name sp2 -> copy the whole row from sheet2 and paste it in sheet 3

There have to be 588 matches, just as a number of rows in sheet1

So far I get to this point. I have no idea where to move further

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/home/russell/Desktop/grumble.xlsx')
ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
ws2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
ws3 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet3')

S1 = set()
S2 = set()

for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=10, max_row=588):
   for cell in row:
      S1.add(cell.value)

for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=16, max_row=3029):
   for cell in row:
      S2.add(cell.value)

print(list(set(S1) & set(S2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create two Pandas dataframes for the sheets to compare and write the resultant frame into the third sheet. See http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html for more information on converting between openpyxl and Pandas.